# Determine if AD account Exists based on firstname lastname

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a txt file that contains a list of names in the format

firstname lastname

How can I check to see whether or not a user exist in AD by getting the content from this list only.  The closest attribute I have in AD is displayName which is in the format of lastname, firstname. Below doesn't work. Thank

```
get-content "c:\temp\file.txt" |
 foreach {
             if (Get-ADUser -Filter {displayName -like $_}){
                 Write-host "$_ does exist in AD"}
              else {
                   Write-host "$_ does not exist in AD"
                   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
    get-content "temp.txt" |
     foreach {
    $givenname,$surname = $_ -split ' '
                 if (Get-ADUser -Filter "surname -eq '$surname' -and givenname -eq '$givenname'"){
                     Write-host "$_ does exist in AD"}
                  else {
                       Write-host "$_ does not exist in AD"
                       }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work better?

```
get-content "c:\temp\file.txt" |
 foreach {
         $filter = [scriptblock]::create("DisplayName -like '*$_*'")
         if (Get-ADUser -Filter $filter){
             Write-host "$_ does exist in AD"}
          else {
               Write-host "$_ does not exist in AD"
               }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
$users = Get-Content "C:\temp\file.txt"

Get-ADUsers -Filter * -Properties givenName,sn | % {
  if ( $users -contains ($_.givenName + " " + $_.sn) ) {
    $_.Name + " exists in AD."
  } else {
    $_.Name + " does not exist in AD."
  }
}
```